# Из Stream<List<Integer>> в List<Integer>

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Как я могу из `Stream<List<Integer>>` сделать `List<Integer>`. Т.е я хочу каждый элемент из всех списков находящихся в потоке собрать в одном списке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так, как предложил автор. Однако есть более используемый способ - flatMap() (как минимум этот метод для этого и сделан)
Вот пример кода:

```
List<Integer> integers1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3));
List<Integer> integers2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(4, 5, 6));
List<Integer> integers3 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(7, 8, 9));

List<Integer> list = Stream.of(integers1, integers2, integers3)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода reduce удалось сложить все списки потока.

```
Stream<List<Integer>> strm = ...;
List<Integer> l = strm.reduce((left, right) -> {
   left.addAll(right);
   return left;
}.get();
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, но реализация хромает.  Во-первых, представленный код просто не компилируется. 
 Во-вторых, он не сработает, если первый список окажется немодифицируемым `List.of`/с постоянной шириной после `Arrays.asList`.  Следует использовать вариант [`reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> acc)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-): `strm.reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (left, right) -> {left.addAll(right); return left;});`